# how to not return nan from answer jquery

Tags: jquery, nan

I've just started learning jquery and I was trying to figure out how to get rid of NAN when there is a space or a letter etc. and change it to nothing? Also is there a better way to write what i've done?

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var one = 9; 
    var two = 7;

    $('#first').keyup(function(){ 
        var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); 
        $('#second').val(firstValue * one / two);
    });

    $('#second').keyup(function(){ 
        var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); 
        $('#first').val(secondValue / two * one);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id=first></input> <input id=second></input>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `input` is a self-closing tag. `<input />`.

Comment: Use `isNaN()` to test if the value is NaN.

Comment: There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/545uhf1r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isNaN()` to test the value before using it.

```
$('#first').keyup(function(){ 
    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val());
    if (!isNan(firstValue) {
        $('#second').val(firstValue * one / two);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var one = 9; 
var two = 7;

$('#first').keyup(function(){ 
    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); 
    if(!isNaN(firstValue))         // Use 'isNaN' as shown
    $('#second').val(firstValue * one / two);
});

$('#second').keyup(function(){ 
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); 
    if(!isNaN(secondValue))        // Use 'isNaN' as shown
    $('#first').val(secondValue / two * one);
});
});
```

Read More here :- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your HTML markup:

```
<input type="text" id="first" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
```

Then, you can do it as recommended by @Barman:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var one = 9; 
    var two = 7;

    $('#first').on('keyup', function(){ 
        var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val());

        if (!isNaN(firstValue)) {
            $('#second').val(firstValue * one / two);
        }
    });

    $('#second').on('keyup', function(){ 
        var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); 

        if (!isNaN(secondValue)) {            
            $('#first').val(secondValue / two * one);
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/545uhf1r/)

[Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)